# Python ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, svm, tf-idf

I'm trying to experiment with linear SVC in my Twitter disaster classi but appear to have come at a dead end, as from the below code.

```
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=0,stratify=y)
```

after the train test spilt ,

```
def run_SVM(clf,x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test ):
  clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
  y_pred=clf.predict(x_test)
  print()
  print('classification Report')
  print(classification_report(y_test , y_pred))
```

and till here I come across no error , but as soon as I do the below

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
clf=LinearSVC()
run_SVM(clf,x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test )
```

I just get  Valuerror as

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead.
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `stratify=y`?

Comment: Welcome to SO :)
Would you please add a portion of `y` array?